# Why is this flask-admin form alway failing validation?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, wtforms

The status field shows the 3 options, but always displays "Not a valid choice" on submisison, whichever is chosen.

```
from website import app, db
from flask.ext import admin
from flask.ext.admin.contrib import sqlamodel
from wtforms.fields import SelectField


class Users(db.Model):
    id     = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name   = db.Column(db.String(160), unique=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class UsersAdmin(sqlamodel.ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(status=SelectField)
    form_args = dict(
        status=dict(
            choices=[(0, 'Regular'), (1, 'Guest'), (2, 'Banned')],
        ))

admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Admin')
admin.add_view(UsersAdmin(Users, db.session))
```

Comment: Are you sure there should be no __validators__ in *form_args['status']*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is likely that the choices are being sent as unicode string while your status field in db is integer. Can you try the following:

```
form_args = dict(
    status=dict(
        choices=[(0, 'Regular'), (1, 'Guest'), (2, 'Banned')],coerce=int
    ))
```

Comment: I had the same problem with the same cause.  I couldn't get the `coerce` option to work so I had to override `validate_form` and `on_form_prefill` to cast the value as described [here](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1504#issuecomment-458127837).